# How to debug React Native (with Expo) app crashes in production?

Tags: expo, react-native

My app is built with the managed Expo flow.

When a crash happens in production, the analytics show me the place in the Java code where it happened. This is useless to me, since I do everything in Javascript.

I'm using expo 38.0.0, and expo-firebase-analytics 2.4.1.

Is there a way to see the exact place in the Javascript code where the crash happened?

Answer (score 0):

I am using sentry free tier to help me solve crash issues in react native expo app.

Please note that, if the crash is due to native device issues, sentry for expo will not helping you.